# Creating new column with values that depends on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

This is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/200911060GSW.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

df = dfs[0] 
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel() # drops the "1st Q" Multilevel header of the dataframe

df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2_level_1': 'PM1', 'Unnamed: 4_level_1': 'PM2'}, inplace=True)
```

then i have made a subset of curry because I focus on his actions.

```
df_curry = df.loc[df["Golden State"].str.contains("Curry", na=False)]
df_curry`
```

now i tried to insert the hit and not hit throws into a new column to calculate the quote later but i always get the error "str' object has no attribute 'str'.
Maybe someone can help me or give me another approach

```
# Calculating Hit Rate

field_throws_missed = 0
field_throws_hit = 0`

# Creating the new Columns
df_curry["Field Goals Hit"] = 0
df_curry["Field Goals Missed"] = 0
df_curry["Field Goals Percentage"] = 0`


for row in range(len(df_curry["Golden State"])):
  if df_curry.iloc[row]["Golden State"].str.contains("misses 2|misses 3"): 
    field_throws_missed += 1
    df_curry.iloc[row]["Field Goals Missed"] = field_throws_missed
  elif df_curry.iloc[row]["Golden State"].str.contains("makes 2|makes 3"): 
    field_throws_hit += 1
    df_curry.iloc[row]["Field Goals Hit"] = field_throws_hit`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loops necessary here, for count `True`s values use cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df_curry = df.loc[df["Golden State"].str.contains("Curry", na=False)].copy()

df_curry["Field Goals Hit"] = df_curry["Golden State"].str.contains("misses 2|misses 3").cumsum()
df_curry["Field Goals Missed"] = df_curry["Golden State"].str.contains("makes 2|makes 3").cumsum()
```

EDIT: If need add `1` in next row use:

```
df_curry["Field Goals Hit"] = df_curry["Golden State"].str.contains("misses 2|misses 3").shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
df_curry["Field Goals Missed"] = df_curry["Golden State"].str.contains("makes 2|makes 3").shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! the problem is that he misses four throws  in the whole game. The code indicates this correctly. But it shows four throws in each row and also in the rows before he has not hit the throws. And I want to have the value in the column only when he has also hit or not hit, that the column is updated with +1 only then.

Comment: @nick.s99 - What is expected output in `Field Goals Hit` column in numbers?

Comment: @nick.s99 - Maybe need `df_curry["Field Goals Hit"] = df_curry["Golden State"].str.contains("misses 2|misses 3").cumsum()` ?

Comment: he only maskes one field goal in row 250. i want the first 249 rows of the column "Field Goals Hit" before that hit as 0 and then after this i want to rows to be 1.

Comment: oh, cumsum is exactly working! thank you a lot!

Comment: @jezrel i have another question. when he misses the throw in row 15 then i get a 1 in the column "Missed throws" but i think it should make more sense when i get the +1 from the missed throw in the next row. do you know how i could do this?